# Computation of Conditional Expectation using Measures

Tags: probability-theory

Here's a definition of conditional expectation of $X$ found on p 363 of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198776195):

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $X$ be
>   in integrable random variable.  If $B \in \mathcal{F}$, $P(B)>0$,
>   define [the conditional probability of $X$ given an event $B$ as] $$ E(X | B) = \frac{E(\mathbb{I}_B X)}{P(B)} $$

I'd like to know how to compute the the numerator, since there seems to be a technicality preventing me from figuring this out, as follows.

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable w.r.t the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.  Then letting $P \circ X^{-1}$ be the pushforward measure on $\mathbb{R}$,
$$
E(g \circ X) = \int_{\Omega} g \circ X\, dP = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g\, d(P \circ X^{-1}).
$$
Then, if $X$ is a continuous random variable we may be able to explicitly compute this using the density $f = \frac{d(P \circ X^{-1})}{d \lambda}$ as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} g\, d(P \circ X^{-1}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} gf\, d\lambda.
$$

To compute our numerator, however, I'm not sure how to write $g$.  One guess is $g(x) = x \mathbb{I}_B$, but I can't really make sense of this...what is the argument for $\mathbb{I}_B$?.  Would it be better to think of $g$ only in terms of the composition, $g \circ X$?  In this case we might have $g(X(\omega)) = X(\omega) \mathbb{I}_B (X(\omega))$, but then this is no longer an indicator on $\Omega$.

I suppose my question then, is, what is $g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable $\omega\mapsto \mathbb{I}_B(\omega)X(\omega)$ is not necessarily of the form $g\circ X$, so your formula for $E(g\circ X)$ is not useful here.

Comment: Okay, so perhaps transforming the $dP$ integral to a $d(P\circ X^{-1})$ integral is not possible...?

Comment: @bcf You are correct; it is not possible.